# Picking data storage type in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

What would you choose for data storage, S3 or EBS, provided no code change should be made in the existing on premise application?

Comment: You can't use EBS with an on-premise application. You can't really use S3 correctly without changing the application code.

Comment: This sounds like a (badly-written) AWS certification question. Is it?

Answer (score 1):

From Documentation made available by Amazon. 
Amazon s3:

```
Amazon S3 has a simple web services interface that you can use to store 
and retrieve any amount of data, at any time, from anywhere on the web.
It gives any developer access to the same highly scalable, reliable, 
fast, inexpensive data storage infrastructure that Amazon uses to run 
its own global network of web sites. The service aims to maximize 
benefits of scale and to pass those benefits on to developers.
```

Amazon EBS:

```
Amazon Elastic Block Store (Amazon EBS) provides persistent block 
storage volumes for use with Amazon EC2 instances in the AWS Cloud. 
Each Amazon EBS volume is automatically replicated within its 
Availability Zone to protect you from component failure, offering high 
availability and durability. Amazon EBS volumes offer the consistent 
and low-latency performance needed to run your workloads. With Amazon 
EBS, you can scale your usage up or down within minutes – all while 
paying a low price for only what you provision.
```

Its clear form their documentation, EBS can only be used by EC2 instances. 
For Example, 
I have hosted a database on my EC2 instance along with my application, The risk in this scenario is that, if my server goes down all my data will be lost with it. Instead of using a managed database by Amazon like RDS,Dynamo, CloudDB (Cost could be a factor), or a database with replication (cost of multiple instances could be a factor), I will attach a EBS with my EC2 instance, I will mount this EBS as a directory and make this directory as a data folder for my Database.

In the event of failure of my EC2 instance, I will detach this EBS and attach to a different server, and All my data will be available again.

Note: You can also take snapshot of your EBS at regular intervals as a safegaurd.

On the other hand, s3 is like a flat file system which works like a CDN.
The basic storage units of Amazon S3 are objects which are organized into buckets. Each object is identified by a unique, user-assigned key.

Amazon S3 is an object storage capable of storing very large objects, upto 5TB in size. S3 is typically used for storing images, videos, logs and other types of files. There is no limit on the number of objects that can be stored in an S3 bucket. Each object in S3 has a url which can be used to download the object. Objects in S3 can also be delivered via Amazon Cloudfront CDN(Content Delivery network). Objects in S3 can be archived to Amazon Glacier which is a very cheap archival service.

Answer (score 0):

- S3 is an object storage - so no
- EBS is a block storage - so yes

However if you are looking for a massive storage to mount to EC2 instance at a cost of S3, you could consider using "AWS Storage Gateway" https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/